# Indoor direction using wifi ESP8266 RSSI

Tags: wifi, esp8266

Am trying to build a small device that is able to determine the direction of object indoor. Not the location, only direction. I bought ESP8266E wifi chip and arduino ESP8266E:
[image: ESP8266E chip as the receiver]

The ESP8266 is the receiver that must read the signal and specify the direction depending on the RSSI. first problem is that the ESP8266 is not directional and the access points around are not directional either . second problem is that the RSSI information takes long time to be read by the ESP8266 . each 3 seconds I can take on measurement. small measurement number make it difficult to analyze the results . I don't know if it is possible to build small directional antenna for the ESP8266E or not . and is the accuracy of the device would be reliable and maintain the device size small or accurate readings ?.
[image: system structure]

Comment: Depends of the resolution you want. A homebrew  coffeecan waveguide antenna could be a solution.

Comment: I second the coffeecan antenna or pringlescan also works... You may want another wifi module that has an SMA or similar connector then... Finally, keep in mind also, modern ac routers use beam forming so RSSI no longer works well for positioning / triangulation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the older ESP-01 model, I'd like to recommend you to use ESP-05. It has no PCB antenna but it provides a pigtail connector. You may connect a directional antenna to it.

[image: ESP-05]